# SQL Multiple Selects - Stacking multiple views and remove duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 7 views which all give a listing of all customers in a database.

Eg.

- View1
- View2
- View3
- View4
- View5
- View6
- View7

Now each view has the potential to contain the same customer across any of these views.

Here is an example of what I currently have using a UNION to bring it all together in the 1 result set:-

```
SELECT
CustomerId,
Account,
Name,
Balance,
'View1' AS [View 1 List]
FROM View1
UNION
SELECT
CustomerId,
Account,
Name,
Balance,
'View2' AS [View 2 List]
FROM View2
UNION
SELECT
CustomerId,
Account,
Name,
Balance,
'View3' AS [View 3 List]
FROM View3
UNION
SELECT
CustomerId,
Account,
Name,
Balance,
'View4' AS [View 4 List]
FROM View4
UNION
SELECT
CustomerId,
Account,
Name,
Balance,
'View5' AS [View 5 List]
FROM View5
UNION
SELECT
CustomerId,
Account,
Name,
Balance,
'View6' AS [View 6 List]
FROM View6
UNION
SELECT
CustomerId,
Account,
Name,
Balance,
'View7' AS [View 7 List]
FROM View7
```

I have 2 problems with this query.

**1.** I want to exclude the customers that are in the first view from appearing in the rest of the views, then keep going up from there. So the customers in View 2 should not contain any customers from View 1. Then view 3 would not have any of the customers if they are already in View 1 and 2. Then view 4 would not have any of the customers if they are already in View 1, 2 and 3. etc: this will go on until the 7th view (View 7 would not have any customers already reported in Views 1,2,3,4,5 and 6)

**2.** This current query produces a column at the end which is titled 'View 1 List' which then identifies which list the customer is in.

What I am looking for is a way to have a column for each View which will identify which view they related to. The value can just be an X or something.

Not sure if this is possible, however I know that I can not do it using a UNION statement.

Comment: If one of these answers was helpful to you, please make sure to mark it as accepted! :-)

Answer (score 2):

`UNION` actually removes duplicates by default, so if the customers in View 2 would match the customers in View 1 across all columns, you don't need to do anything there.

**UPDATE:** As @Diego pointed out below, my original solution to that would have eliminated this advantage, since providing a column or columns for the view would eliminate the duplication. One solution is to do the `UNION` first as a CTE, usion `UNION` to remove duplicates for you, and *then* figure out the view they're coming from.

```
WITH UnionCTE AS
(
  SELECT
  CustomerId,
  Account,
  Name,
  Balance
  FROM View1

  UNION

  SELECT
  CustomerId,
  Account,
  Name,
  Balance
  From View2

  UNION
  ...
)
SELECT UnionCTE.*,
  CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM View1 WHERE CustomerId = UnionCTE.CustomerID) THEN 'View1'
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM View2 WHERE CustomerId = UnionCTE.CustomerID) THEN 'View2'
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM View3 WHERE CustomerId = UnionCTE.CustomerID) THEN 'View3'
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM View4 WHERE CustomerId = UnionCTE.CustomerID) THEN 'View4'
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM View5 WHERE CustomerId = UnionCTE.CustomerID) THEN 'View5'
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM View6 WHERE CustomerId = UnionCTE.CustomerID) THEN 'View6'
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM View7 WHERE CustomerId = UnionCTE.CustomerID) THEN 'View7'
  END AS [ViewNumber]
FROM UnionCTE
```

The above will create a single column that shows you the source of the data. If you want a separate column for each view, you could use the following after the CTE:

```
SELECT UnionCTE.*,
  CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM View1 WHERE CustomerId = UnionCTE.CustomerID) THEN 'X' 
    END AS [View1],
  CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM View2 WHERE CustomerId = UnionCTE.CustomerID) THEN 'X'
    END AS [View2],
    ...
  CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM View7 WHERE CustomerId = UnionCTE.CustomerID) THEN 'X'
    END AS [View7]
FROM UnionCTE
```

Comment: Would it not make more sense to just have a column `SourceView` that has an `int` or `tinyint` with the view ID?

Comment: @JNK yes, I think so, but OP already has something like that (except with a varchar), and doesn't seem to want that.

Comment: I'm afraid that a simple UNION won't work, as the rows returned by View1 will never be a duplicate of rows from oher views. This is because of the "View ID" column(s), which will make the rows different.

Comment: You mention that UNION will already remove the duplicates, however wouldn't the having all those columns with a different location for the X value cause there to be duplicates between all 7 unions?

Comment: @Diego & user1933532 that's a good point, it totally escaped me. I have an idea to fix that.

Comment: Okay, I have a new approach above.

Answer (score 0):

One more option with CTE, UNION ALL and [RANK()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) ranking function

```
 ;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT CustomerId, Account, Name, Balance, 'View1' AS [ViewList]
  FROM View1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CustomerId, Account, Name, Balance, 'View2'
  FROM View2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CustomerId, Account, Name, Balance, 'View3'
  FROM View3
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CustomerId, Account, Name, Balance, 'View4'
  FROM View4
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CustomerId, Account, Name, Balance, 'View5'
  FROM View5
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CustomerId, Account, Name, Balance, 'View6'
  FROM View6
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CustomerId, Account, Name, Balance, 'View7'
  FROM View7
  ), cte2 AS
 (
  SELECT *, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerId ORDER BY [ViewList] ASC) AS rn
  FROM cte  
  )
  SELECT *
  FROM cte2
  WHERE rn = 1
```

Simple example on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ca6ba/1)